# How to update text inside Div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Iam trying to update Div text based on js variable null or not.

This is the code  used for checking var userName is null or not.
If its null i dont want to do anything.But if userName is not null then i need to append ',' to existing text inside div .

```
 $("document").ready(function (){
    var userName = "";
    if (userName == undefined || userName == null) {
        alert('empty');
    } else {
        alert('not empty');
        var div = document.getElementById('title b');
        div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + ','; 
    }
});
```

my html of the div

```
<div id="title" class="box">
<b>Welcome</b>
</div>
```

For example if  userName is not null then i want div text as "Welcome ,"

if userName is null then i want div text as "Welcome"

Comment: you declared var userName = ""; then how could it became undefined or null?

Comment: `document.getElementById('title b')`. Your example has no element with this ID. Also, if you're using jQuery, then use jQuery, and don't do stuff like `var div = document.getElementById('title b');
        div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + ',';`

Comment: my div id is "title" and inside that text is bold . so i given title b

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using jQuery already...

```
 $(document).ready(function (){
    var userName = ""; // this will never get into the following if statement, always else

    if (userName == undefined || userName == null) { // use if (!userName) as shorthand.
        alert('empty');
    } else {
        alert('not empty');
        var div = $('#title > b');
        div.text(div.text() + ','); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't you mean `div.text(div.text() +',')`?

Comment: Edited after I saw he needed to use the b tag. You can use html or text though.

Answer (score 1):

You're using an odd mix of POJS and jQuery here. Here's a purely jQuery solution:

```
$("document").ready(function (){
    var userName = "";
    if (userName == undefined || userName == null) {
        alert('empty');
    } else {
        alert('not empty');
        $('#title b').append(','); 
    }
});
```

It's a little odd that you're declaring `userName` as an empty string within your function - the first `if` condition will *never* execute.

Answer (score 0):

A more `jQuery` answer, if you are interested:

```
var userName = "";
//var userName = "User";   // for testing
//var userName;            // for testing
//var userName = null;     // for testing

$(document).ready(function (){
    var greeting = !!userName ? "Welcome, "+ userName + "!" : "Welcome";

    $("#title b").html(greeting);
})
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gavin42/8Zkzr/)